# Running an IBM Notes Java Application on OS X El Capitan throws UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, lotus-notes, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to run a HelloWord Java application that accesses the Notes client on a Mac. I had that working on older versions. Currently I have Java 1.8.0_101-b13 an OS/X 10.11.6. I try to run this code:

```
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import lotus.domino.NotesThread;
import lotus.domino.Session;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NotesException {
    HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
    hw.sayHello();
  }

  private void sayHello() throws NotesException {
    System.out.println("java.library.path: "+ System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    System.out.println("PATH: "+ System.getenv("PATH"));
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
    System.out.println(s.getEffectiveUserName());
    NotesThread.stermThread();
  }
}
```

I've set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/IBM Notes.app` in an Eclipse run configuration. When I run the app I get:

> java.library.path: /Applications/IBM Notes.app:/Users/joe/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
>       PATH: /Applications/IBM Notes.app:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lsxbe in java.library.path
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>           at lotus.domino.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source)
>           at lotus.domino.NotesThread.checkLoaded(Unknown Source)
>           at lotus.domino.NotesThread.sinitThread(Unknown Source)
>           at com.notessensei.HelloWorld.sayHello(HelloWorld.java:31)
>           at com.notessensei.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:20)

The library path looks OK. I must be missing something obvious?

**Update**: When you look at the output, Java picks up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, so `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` seems not to be needed (I added it to test to no avail). DYLD... seems to [be problematic](https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch/issues/111) on OS/X.

One thought which isn't clear: In the OS/X world you usually point to the App (IBM Notes.app), but the content is actually in `appname.app/Contents/MacOS`. I think I tried both with the same result. Does the space in the path throw up?

**Update 2**: As requested the output of `otool -L liblsxbe.dylib`

> liblsxbe.dylib:
>       @executable_path/liblsxbe.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libxmlproc.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libnotes.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 157.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

`otool -L libxmlproc.dylib`

> libxmlproc.dylib:
>       @executable_path/libxmlproc.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libnotes.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 157.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

`otool -L libnotes.dylib'

> libnotes.dylib:
>       @executable_path/libnotes.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libjsmac.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libndgts.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libxmlproc.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       @executable_path/libgsk8iccs.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55471.14.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 20.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 157.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.14.0)
>       /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1265.19.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 673.2.1)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59.0.0)

What else?

Comment: It's `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`on Mac OS X

Comment: @user2543253 not anymore: https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch/issues/111 blocked on El Captain. And I did set that too - amending the question

Comment: Ah, good to know, thank you. But is the lib actually in `/Applications/IBM Notes.app`? I'd rather expect `/Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOSX`

Comment: it is `Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOS` without the X, but I tried that too. Not asking question lightly ;-)

Comment: Would the "older version" be a 32-bit java?  Libraries need to match :-/

Comment: OS/X 10.11.4, Java 8.0 some earlier version, if I recall correctly and 64Bit all the way (the beauty of Mac: client is 64Bit like the servers).

Comment: Read your update. You say that Java picks up "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" but does the Mac OS X dynamic loader do too? The library has its own dependencies. Can you check if the output of `otool -L` looks good?

Comment: Updated questions with otool -L results

Comment: It's been a while but doesn't "@executable_path" specify the location where the application is? Which in your case would be `java`? Did you also try DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much probing it turned out to be 2 issues to be solved. The first one, is described in a [post by Mikkel Flint Heisterberg](http://lekkimworld.com/2016/09/04/developing_plugins_for_ibm_notes_on_mac.html). Besides `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` another environment variable needs to be set: `NOTESBIN`. Both point at the same location:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOS
NOTESBIN=/Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOS
```

No quotes or backslashes are needed in the Eclipse run configuration.

The second one was trickier. Out of convenience, since it worked prior, I had created a new entry "installed JVM's" called 'Notes9'. There I pointed to the Oracle JVM8 (yep, on Mac Notes is running Java8) *and* the Notes.jar (and the others) in `jvm/lib/ext` of the Notes program directory.

Mac doesn't like that (anymore). Once I pointed to a "naked" JVM8 and added Notes.jar as external Jar dependency, everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with almost the same issue. I did as you did in the first part of your answer, that is setting the environment variables in Eclipse to the following

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOS
NOTESBIN=/Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOS
```

I also wrote in my `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myuser/bin:/Applications/IBM\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS
```

And in my `.profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/IBM\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS
export PATH=$PATH

# Update bashrc 
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I have been using Eclipse Mars while trying to figure this out, but it seemed like neither PATH nor `java.library.path` was correct. I was fed up with Mars, and decided to download Oxygen. I don't know why, but after I installed Oxygen, added the environment variables to Eclipse, and using Java 1.8, I was able to get my effective username with your example, and the same solution worked on a larger application we are developing.

I am only adding this answer as an addition to your answer. I am glad I found this question on SO. Thank you.